# What does ''event.pos[0]'' mean in the pygame library? I saw an example using it to get the X axis of the cursor and ignore the Y axis

Tags: python, events, pygame, mouseevent

I don't understand how it works. I don't know if I understood the purpose of this function wrong. I tried to search what `posx=event.pos[0]` means but all I found was that if you want to take `x`, write the code of `posx,posy=pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and then take `posx`. But I still can't understand the method he followed in the example I saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`pygame.event` module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html). The `MOUSEMOTION`, `MOUSEBUTTONUP` and `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events provide a position property `pos` with the position of the mouse cursor. `pos` is a tuple with 2 components, the x and y coordinate.

e.g.:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print("mouse cursor x", event.pos[0])
        print("mouse cursor y", event.pos[1])
```

[`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) returns a [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequencesv) and `event.pos` is a [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Both give you the position of the mouse pointer as a tuple with 2 components:

```py
ex, ey = event.pos
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

[`pygame.mouse.getpos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) returns the current position of the mouse. The `pos` attribute stores the position of the mouse when the event occurred. Note that you can call `pygame.event.get()` much later than the event occurred. If you want to know the position of the mouse at the time of the event, you can call it up using the `pos` attribute.

Comment: firstly, thanks I now understood that event.pos[] can take two parameters 0 or 1 (zero return x cursor and one for y cursor) but pygame.mouse.getpos() return (x,y) cursor together,right?

Comment: @roroeiad Sorry you lack the basics. `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` returns a [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequencesv) and `event.pos` is a [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). You get `(x, y)` from both. However, you can get the components of a Tuple with  `t[i]`. e.g.: `pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]` or `event.pos[0]`.